# Returning the ID of a blank object during creation process

Tags: java, mongodb

I would like to make an object, get its '_id', change it to a String and pass that as an argument to another object.

Thoughts were something like this, but its not working

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
a.insert(doc);
String id = doc.getString("$oid");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
ObjectId myId = new ObjectId(); //id is created here
DBObject myObject = new BasicDBObject();
myObject.put("_id", myId);

// Whether you save myObject to Mongo or not at this moment, you have its id
String myIdString = myId.toString();
// Now you can save myObject's id string in another object, and then later on,
// If you want to recreate the myId object you can do so:
ObjectId myIdRecreated = new ObjectId(myIdString);
```

In other words, instantiating an ObjectId and passing it to the "_id" field of a DBObject will mean that that ObjectId will be the id for that DBObject. In this way you don't need to explicitly save the DBObject to Mongo to have its id.